# Mozilla Drop Down Arrow

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to remove the dropdown arrow from Mozilla Firefox

```
select{
                -moz-appearance: none;
                text-indent: 0.01px;
                text-overflow: '';
                -moz-appearance: window; 
                -webkit-appearance: button;
                -moz-appearance: button;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -webkit-padding-end: 20px;
                -moz-padding-end: 20px;
                -webkit-padding-start: 2px;
                -moz-padding-start: 2px;
                background: transparent;
                border: none;}
```

M-moz-appearance doesnt seem to work?

Thanks

Comment: I am also facing the same problem @steve :(

Comment: Do you any good jquery work arounds?

Comment: Try -moz-appearance:window